# Cloud-front backed with Nginx (which proxies to S3) randomly missing already cached items?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I wish to serve images from a **S3 bucket** with **Cloudfront** as CDN frontend, for that I tried the following:

> What I **wish to acheive** (**Attempt 2**)  -- (**Misses cloudfront cache randomly**)

I have the following setup to serve images: ( **Cloudfront** --> **Nginx** --> **S3** )
[image: Cloudfront -> Nginx -> S3]

<<<<<<<< Sample **S3** headers >>>>>>>>>>
[image: Attempt-2 S3 headers]

<<<<<<<< Sample **Nginx -> S3** headers (Added **Cache-Control**) >>>>>>>>>>
[image: Attempt-2 Nginx->S3 headers]

<<<<<<<< Sample **Cloudfront -> Nginx -> S3** headers >>>>>>>>>>
[image: Attempt-2 Cloudfront->Nginx->S3 headers]

> What I am **currently working** with (**Attempt 1**) -- (**Hits cloudfront as expected everytime**)

[image: Cloudfront -> S3]

** Cloudfront Settings **:

- Respects `GET` params to support urls like (http://cdn.example.com/abc.jpg?v=1)
- Cache `TTL` set to **157680000** ( Fallback for ***Cache-Control*** )

What am I screwing up in **Attemp-2** with my headers ? ( **Cloudfront missing randomly** )

Url(http://cdn.example.com/abc.jpg) & Url(http://cdn.example.com/abc.jpg?v=1) both will have same `ETag`, is that fine ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is related to the clients making requests that indicate that cache should be by-passed?

E.g., maybe [`Pragma: no-cache`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314174/difference-between-pragma-and-cache-control-headers/15050018#15050018) appears in the requests, and is respected by the front-facing server, resulting in a miss?

Comment: Since my access method remains same every-time, this should not be the case. This would have resulted in constant `miss`

Comment: What are your access methods?  Do you use a browser?  When you click various refresh and shift-refresh or whatever, they do send these extra no-cache headers.

Comment: I have tried all `browser`, `curl`, `wget`, etc. Though, I didn't checked the defaults. Shouldn't it miss everytime if its the case that you are talking about.

Comment: Why would it miss all the time?  You don't always have these extra no-cache headers flying around.  Also, maybe there's some extra logic involved in cloudfront.net of when the no-cache directives are respected, and when not.  If the above is not an answer, then, IMHO, the question is probably off-topic for serverfault.

Comment: Interesting, `extra logic` in cloudfront.net. Let me dig into that.

Comment: Here are my request-headers with `curl`: `User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3`, `Host: example.com`, `Accept: */*`

Comment: See this discussion for more : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=144286&tstart=0#

Comment: Cloud front is pull-only. Nginx may screw headers in case of using caching headers and gzipping (which is equal to modifying) the response.